# Word for legal counsel/representative

Tags: canada, legal-terms

I'm representing my wife in a minor legal case (I'm more comfortable with the formal aspects than she is), but I'd rather avoid describing myself as the husband of the accused.

Is there a more formal word to describe this? I'm not sure if "legal counsel" is accurate/allowed, and I definitely can't say I'm her attorney (I'm not a lawyer).

Comment: If you're not a lawyer, how and why are you acting like one and representing your wife?

Comment: Yeah it really is lawyer, but advocate might be the word your thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that you can't represent anyone else if you haven't been called to the bar, but there are some things that you are allowed to do (from [the National Self-Represented Litigants Program](https://representingyourselfcanada.com/)):

1. You can help prepare her case before it gets to trial. There are plenty of resources that you can use, and it may be helpful to get the services of a lawyer for specific issues if you need to ("unbundled services").
2. You can [apply to be a McKenzie Friend](https://representingyourselfcanada.com/the-mckenzie-friend-choosing-and-presenting-a-courtroom-companion/), to help manage documents and take notes. Check with the court to see if this is available.

I am not a lawyer, but this is an area that is of interest to me. However, check with a lawyer and the court if you have specific questions, because different courts have different procedures that you need to follow, and they can assist you with getting the correct documents to file and timelines to abide by (court staff can't give legal advice!)

Answer (score 1):

The word is **lawyer**.

In most places and in most courts, a person who is not a properly qualified and registered lawyer is not allowed to represent another person. Doing so is usually a crime.

Comment: This. I'd also have said *attorney of record* when referring to a case, or the word *solicitor* for us British folks as we don't really use the word attorney over here